# xUnit Setup function not being called

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a very basic unit test. For some reason the test passed only the first time but all subsequent calls have failed. Here is the test code:

```
private Mock<IMyInterface> _mockObject;
public Test() {
   _mockObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
}

[Fact]
public void ItReturnsTheRightThing() {
   _mockObject.SetUp(o => o.FunctionIWantToMock()).Returns(new SpecialObject(true));
   var classIWantToTest = new ClassIWantToTest(_mockObject.Object);
   classIWantToTest.RunCode();
   ...
}
```

The interface:

```
internal interface IMyInterface {
    SpecialObject FunctionIWantToMock();
}
```

The production code:

```
public class ClassIWantToTest {
    IMyInterface _client;
    internal ClassIWantToTest(IMyInterface client) {
        _client = client;
    }
    public bool RunCode() {
        SpecialObject so = _client.FunctionIWantToMock();
        return so.Value; // This line is the problem
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run my test, my mock function isn't returning what I setup in the SetUp function, it's not returning the `SpecialObject(true)` but rather `null`. I then get a null reference exception. When I debug the test, I can't step into the `_client.FunctionIWantToMock` call, it just immediately steps to the next line and populates `so` with null.

Comment: @Fabio that's just a typo when i was typing up this question, I'll change it.

Comment: @Fabio I'm getting a null reference exception when trying to access a property of the `so` variable. `so` itself is null, because the call `_client.FunctionIWantToMock()` is returning null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, I would try something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void ItReturnsTheRightThing() {
    _mockObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
   _mockObject.SetUp(o => o.FunctionIWantToMock()).Returns(new SpecialObject(true));
   var classIWantToTest = new ClassIWantToTest(_mockObject.Object);
   classIWantToTest.RunCode();
  ...
}
```

Try this and if it works, something interferes with the mock object in between

Comment: But my code above does the same thing, other than creating the mock object in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

A coworker helped me figure out the issue. It is also my fault that I obfuscated too much of the original code when writing up this question.

The problem was that I was passing explicit parameters to the `o.FunctionIWantToMock()` method during the setup, that did not match the explicit parameters passed to the function in the business logic. So the actual test code was `o.FunctionIWantToMock("foo", "bar")`. In my business logic, the actual function is called with `_client.FunctionIWantToMock("Foo", "Bar")`. So because the parameters didn't match ("Foo" vs "foo", "Bar" vs "bar") the SetUp wasnt actually setting up my actual code. I changed the setUp function to

`o.FunctionIWantToMock(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())`